# Any way to run an internal python script from a webpage?

Tags: python

I finally made a project that I wanted to make since a long time :

I'm using an Arduino Uno to replace my PC power button (with a simple relay) and that Arduino Board is connected to a Raspi 3 for network connection purposes

My wish is to do a webpage (or a API-Like request) that at a touch of a button (preferably in a password-protected page) It'll power the PC on

I know how to code in Python, and my script to control the Arduino is already done but I can't find a way to run, only server-side, a Python Script from a button in a webpage

I found that [CherryPy](https://cherrypy.org/) framework but I don't think it'll suit my needs

Can someone give me any ideas about that please?

Comment: "a way to run, only server-side, a Python Script from a button in a webpage" - Flask, Django, Bottle - any Python web server. Bottle is probably the most lightweight. Or simply roll your own with the built-in `http.server`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by @ForceBru, you need a python webserver.

If this can be useful to you, this is a possible **unsecure** implementation using flask:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/turnOn')
def hello_world():
    k = request.args.get('key')
    if k == "superSecretKey":
        # Do something ..
        return 'Ok'
    else:
        return 'Nope'
```

If you put this in an *app.py* name file and, after having installed flask (`pip install flask`), you run `flask run` you should be able to see *Ok* if visiting the url *http://localhost:5000/turnOn?key=superSecretKey* .

You could write a brief html gui with a button and a key field in a form but I leaves that to you (you need to have fun too!).
To avoid potential security issues you could use a POST method and https.
Look at the [flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) for more infos.

Comment: That's great all the way, thank you very much